# Color code due date field if 6 months before current date

Tags: javascript, jslink

I have this specific requirement to color code the *due date* field if it's value is less than 180 days (6 months) compared to today's date.

Is this possible with Javascript/JSLink ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes absolutely.  Here's a quick code example that I mostly [borrowed from here](http://www.tuomi.ca/2014/09/25/conditional-color-coding-sharepoint-2013-task-list-using-jslink/):

```
(function () {
    var statusFieldCtx = {};

    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "DueDate": {
            "View": ColorCodeDueDate
            }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function ColorCodeDueDate(ctx) {
    var dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.DueDate);

    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();
    then.setDate(now.getDate() + 180);

    // if there's no due date don't render anything
    if (dueDate == 'undefined' || !dueDate) {
        return '';
    }
    else if (dueDate >= now && dueDate <= then) { // we are within 180 days
        return "<div style='background-color:red;color:white'>" + dueDate.toLocaleDateString() + "</div>";
    }
    else {  // we are outside of 180 days
        return "<div>" + dueDate.toLocaleDateString() + "</div>";
    }
}
```

---

If your field's *internal name* is "MaxEndDate", change the line

```
"DueDate:" {
```

to

```
"MaxEndDate": {
```

and then change the line

```
var dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.DueDate);
```

to

```
var dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.MaxEndDate);
```

The color is just defined using the inline CSS style of the `div` markup you are returning.  In the code example above, I am returning a `div` with a red background and white text.  If all you need is red text on the default background, you would do something like

```
return "<div style='color:red'>" + dueDate.toLocaleDateString() + "</div";
```

Comment: The color should be RED if the value is within 180 days, i.e 179 days. what piece in the code do I need to modify? my field is actually named "MaxEndDate"

Comment: this section, style='background-color:red;color:white' gives you white text on a red backgroud, if you just want red text, then do color:red

Comment: @Eric Alexander. to target my field "MaxEndDate", do I only replace "DueDate" in statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields  section ? I read somewhere that this where the field is set for manipulation.

Comment: @LuisCarvalho please see my update, you need to reference your real field name in two places.

Comment: @Dylan Cristy  , for some reason the MaxEnddate is now incorrectly formating the date. the format should be DD/MM/YYYY. if I edit the field value, the format is changed to MM/DD/YYYY. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The difference in formats sounds like a localization setting, maybe.  But, I can't tell you why it would be formatted one way and then change only after an edit.

Comment: it is only happing in this field. I have other date fileds in this list and it is fine. As is said, prior to this code the field was formatting the date correctly. In fact, when I remove the JSLink the field works correctly again

Comment: Then it probably has to do with how the date is getting formatted by using the `date.ToLocaleDateString()` method.  You should investigate other ways of getting formatted dates from Javascript `Date` objects in order to get the formatting that you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I just need to output the date to this format DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: Try `dueDate.toLocaleDateString("en-GB")`.  Please also read this web page about `toLocaleDateString()` so you can learn about how to use `toLocaleDateString()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Unfortunately this code is completing messing my dates. even when I type the English US format, i.e. MM/DD/YYYY it does not always work correctly. when I use 08/25/2016 it will not accept the date (red marks it). also tried dueDate.toLocaleDateString("en-GB") but still does not work.

Comment: Date entry has nothing to do with how CSR displays it; the Site (settings) Locale setting determines how you can enter dates

Comment: @Danny Engelman. My Locale is  english united kingdom. As I said I have not problems if I remove the code. Please read the entire post..

Comment: I am getting somewhere. it seams date if I change my Locale to English US, then the code works correctly

Answer (score 1):

I whipped this up quick, works on a standard Task List.

[image]

```
function ColorCodeDueDate(ctx) {
  var fieldname=ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.RealFieldName,
      datevalue=new Date(ctx.CurrentItem[fieldname]),
      days=GetDaysAfterToday(datevalue);
  if (!days) return 'No '+fieldname;
  if (days<5) style="background-color:red;color:white";
  if (days<-30) style="background-color:green;color:white";
  return String.format("<div style='{0}'>{1} days from {2:dd/MM/yyyy}</div>",style,days,datevalue);
}
```

Notes:

- Use the [Chrome Extension Cisar](https://365csi.nl/cisar) (by Andrei Markeev) to code CSR files.
- Should be easy to spot how to change it to your 180 days
- Do **not** hardcode internal fieldnames; this function can be applied to any DateTime field
- Try to code with only one exit point (return) in your functions; makes it a lot easier to read
- **GetDaysAfterToday()** comes from SharePoints own `sp.datetimeutil.js` library, but you might have to load it as extra JSLink first; because SP loads it **after** your CSR code executes
  (OR copy that function code into your own CSR file)
- **String.format()** comes from  SharePoints `msajaxbundle.js`; which is loaded **before** your CSR code executes

[image]

#### With the https://iCSR.github.io Library you do not have to write a function at all

If you declare the View as:

```
'MaxEndDate':{
  View : iCSR.DueDate({
                        ranges:'[msRed],0,#FFF1AD,90,[msGreen]'
                        ,rowcolor:true
                        })
}
```

You get this: (screenshot from another post)

- msRed and msGreen are [iCSR](https://iCSR.github.io) *tokens* matching the colors from the new Microsoft Planner
- iCSR adjusts the textcolor contrast for you (*on each cell, you can't set a textcolor on a TR row*)
- and more

[image]

Comment: this is still messing my dates. unless I change my locale to English US, which defeats the purpose.