# Sharepoint DueDate

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, jquery-ui

I have a task list and i want to filter the items like below.

i.  The first View should be filtered to only show documents that are 0-30 Days Past Due.Yellow for documents that are 0-30 days past due

ii. The second View should be filtered to only show documents that are 30-60 Days Past Due.Red for document that are 30-60 days past due

Can any one help on the same

Answer (score 1):

This is not Filtering, but highlight (a row) with color based on a (due) date

Multiple options:

- [Color code due date field if 6 months before current date](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172731/color-code-due-date-field-if-6-months-before-current-date/172980#172980)
- [Calculated formulas for tracking progress](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162343/calculated-formulas-for-tracking-progress/162344?s=1|0.1634#162344)
- [Conditional Formatting Based on Number Range](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178358/conditional-formatting-based-on-number-range/178408#178408)
- [Color code due date field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180930/color-code-due-date-field/180954#180954)

Or even more: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A32871+due