# Color Coding a column based on a date

Tags: 2010, column

I found a great article on color coding a list item based on dates.  However, this only works for 2 days within submission.  I am trying to have a coding structure that will let me know when something is late.  This is the information I am using:

I have a column that subtracts the two dates, then I have another column that uses this script:

```
="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&CHOOSE((IF(SubmissionDateDifference<=2,2,1)),"red","green","orange")&";'>•</DIV>"
```

With this script, it is only given me the Red and Green colors depending on if the date is greater than 2 days or less than 2 days.  I would like to have it give me Red for 0 days and green for greater than 0.  When I tried to change the numbers to <=0,0, the formula didn't work.

Also, the final piece in case you were wondering is setting up a web part with the list and below the list is a CEWP with this HTML Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//
// Text to HTML
// Demo: sharepoint.infoyen.com by Avinash Kumar Dad
//
var cellTDs = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
var i=0;
var TDContent = " ";
while (i < cellTDs.length) {
try {
TDContent = cellTDs[i].innerText || cellTDs[i].textContent;
if ((TDContent.indexOf("<DIV") == 0) && (TDContent.indexOf("</DIV>") >= 0)) {
cellTDs[i].innerHTML = TDContent;
}
}
catch(err){}
i=i+1;
}
//
// ExpGroupRenderData overwrites the default SharePoint function
// This part is needed for collapsed groupings
//
function ExpGroupRenderData(htmlToRender, groupName, isLoaded) {
   var tbody=document.getElementById("tbod"+groupName+"_");
   var wrapDiv=document.createElement("DIV");
   wrapDiv.innerHTML="<TABLE><TBODY id=\"tbod"+ groupName+"_\" isLoaded=\""+isLoaded+ "\">"+htmlToRender+"</TBODY></TABLE>";
   var tBODYTDs = wrapDiv.getElementsByTagName("TD"); var j=0; var cellTDContent = " ";
   while (j < tBODYTDs.length) {
      try {
         cellTDContent = tBODYTDs[j].innerText || tBODYTDs[j].textContent;
         if ((cellTDContent.indexOf("<DIV") == 0) && (cellTDContent.indexOf("</DIV>") >= 0)) {
           tBODYTDs[j].innerHTML = cellTDContent;
         }
     }
     catch(err){}
     j=j+1;
  }
  tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapDiv.firstChild.firstChild,tbody);
}
```

The link for this assistance came from

http://sharepoint.infoyen.com/2014/07/01/add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists-using-calculated-columns/

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I needed to add a couple of items to this post.  This is working inside a library that is pulled from an InfoPath form.  Also in my pull for color coding, I would only like it to be red if the date difference is 0 and the status is not = to complete.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

As you see in the first Comment of that Blog you refer to,
that (SP2007 approach) CEWP to convert Calculated Column HTML text to innerHTML
is totally **not** needed.

Full explanation how to do HTML in Calculated Columns (since SP2010): http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

**Read all the Cons of this method!** and why you should use the Microsoft CSR - Client Side Rendering (since SP2013) method (and do use the WYSYWIG CSR editor [Cisar](https://365csi.nl/cisar)!)

There are multiple answers here on SO doing what you want (with CCs or CSR):

- [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)
- [Color code due date field if 6 months before current date](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172731/color-code-due-date-field-if-6-months-before-current-date/172980#172980)
- [Calculated formulas for tracking progress](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162343/calculated-formulas-for-tracking-progress/162344?s=1|0.1634#162344)
- [Conditional Formatting Based on Number Range](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178358/conditional-formatting-based-on-number-range/178408#178408)
- [Color code due date field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180930/color-code-due-date-field/180954#180954)

Or even more: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A32871+due

iCC iCSR iDATE iDUE

Comment: +1 Another that I've found is that REST API for the list can break when calculated columns are present using this hack. Please use XSL, JSLink or other CSR methods--it's so much friendlier to SharePoint.